# Delete row in native css grid

Tags: html, css

I need to be able to delete a row in a native css grid.. but since we're just specifying the columns and the rows are automatic I cant find a way.. Is there a way to wrap the column divs that wont affect the grid layout?

Heres what I have and a fiddle:

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="id0" class="col colSpan3"></div>
  <div class="col rowSpan2"></div>
  <div class="col rowSpan2"></div>
  <div class="col rowSpan2"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  max-width: 960px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 6px;
}

.col {
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
}

.colSpan2 { grid-column: auto / span 2;}
.colSpan3 { grid-column: auto / span 3;}

.rowSpan2 { grid-row: auto / span 2;}
.rowSpan3 { grid-row: auto / span 3;}
```

js:

```
var id0 = document.getElementById("id0");
id0.onclick = function() { id0.remove();  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/x8t0a82b/1/

I can delete the first row here as it spans all columns, but I'm not able to find a way to delete the entire row.

Comment: You mean and keep the elements in row 2? No, unless you define the rows.

Comment: Yes.. I found a solution though.. In my main project I added a class to all the content that I want to delete from js and then used the getElementsByClassName function and then deleted all thoese elements.. I don't know if that is a good way though.. feels like the html gets a little cluttered with extra classes on alot of elements..

Answer (score 1):

Usee Css variables for the job:

```
:root {
  --rowNum: 4;
  --colNum: 5;
  --gridHeight: 120px;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(var(--rowNum), var(--gridHeight));
  grid-template-columns: repeat(var(--colNum), auto);
}
.grid-item {
  grid-column-start: auto;
  grid-row-start: auto;
  margin: 5px;
}

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
  <div class="grid-item"></div>
</div>

function del() {  
  $('.grid-item:last-child').parentNode.removeChild($('.grid-item:last-child'));
  updateVar();
}

function updateVar(action) {
  let htmlStyles = window.getComputedStyle($("html"));
  let rowNum = parseInt(htmlStyles.getPropertyValue("--rowNum"));
  let colNum = parseInt(htmlStyles.getPropertyValue("--colNum"));
  let gridItemsCount = document.querySelectorAll('.grid-item').length;
  document.documentElement.style.setProperty(`--rowNum`, Math.ceil(gridItemsCount/colNum));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a class on each of the elements, then use `.querySelectorAll()` to remove them:

**HTML**

```
<div id='theGrid'>
    ...
    <div class='cell1 row1'>1-1</div>
    <div class='cell2 row1'>2-1</div>
    <div class='cell3 row1'>3-1</div>
    ...
</div>
```

**JS**

```
const grid = document.getElementById('theGrid');

Array.from(grid.querySelectorAll('row1'))
    .forEach(domNode => domNode.parentNode.removeChild(domNode));
```